# Question about the convolution $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]} * \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

I'm pretty new to convolutions and I had to evaluate the convolution $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]} * \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$

I found the following solution:
$$\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]} * \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]} (x) =
\begin{cases}
0 \qquad x \le 0 \\
x \qquad 0<x<1 \\
1 \qquad x=1 \\
2-x \quad 1<x<2 \\
0 \qquad x\ge 2
\end{cases}$$

**edit**

I know the following theorem holds:

> For every $f,g \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have $\ \text{supp}(f*g) \subseteq \text{supp}(f) + \text{supp}(g)$

But as you can see the two functions above are not continous but anyway the theorem seems to hold. My question is:

> How can I generalize that theorem? In other words, what are the minimalist hypothesis on $f$ and $g$ such that $\ \text{supp}(f*g) \subseteq \text{supp}(f) + \text{supp}(g)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuity is not required at all really, but you need to be careful about the word "support", because evaluating functions $f \in L^1$ is not quite kosher (technically, functions in $L^1$ are defined only up to a.e. equality.) However, if $f, g \in L^1$ are supported on sets $X, Y$, meaning $f \equiv 0 $ in $X^c$ and $g \equiv 0$ in $Y^c$, then $f * g$ is supported on $X+Y$. This is immediate from the definition of convolution. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support.

Comment: What you say has enough sense to me, but I was not asking for the support of $f+g$ but for the support of $f*g$, the convolution between $f$ and $g$. Also, $f, g$ in my "theorem" were taken in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and not in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: I meant $f*g$, $f+g$ was a typo